# react class method is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am new in react. My app was running properly, but after adding eslint(airbnb), my apps failed to compile.

```
export default class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.message}</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.helloWorldClick}>Hello 
        World</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  helloWorldClick = () => {
    console.log('here') 
  }
}
```

Before adding { "parser": "babel-eslint" } on .eslintrc file, it was throwing the eslint error

> "[eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token =" --on the helloWorldClick arrow function line.

After adding parser, i don't have any elsint error. But got compiled error to run the app.

> Failed to compile
>     ./src/component/HelloWorldComponent.js
>     Line 18:  'helloWorldClick' is not defined  no-undef

Please let me know how can I solve this error.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the arrow function that's causing a problem here. Class properties are not part of the ES6 specification.

If you want to be able to transform this code, you'll need to add the [class properties babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Alternatively, this transform is provided as part of Babel's [stage 2 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/).

Using an arrow function with a class property ensures that the method is always invoked with the component as the value for this, meaning that the manual rebinding here is redundant.

```
this.helloWorldClick = this.helloWorldClick.bind (this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem aswell.  You can add the following to the top each component file to prevent the 'un-def' keywork error message and still use arrow functions without changing the es-lint settings.

```
/* eslint no-undef: 0 */ // --> OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. But my problem was different. Finally I solved this. By downgrade eslint version to 3.19.0. Its perfectly working now.